# Xamarin.Android random number picks same number multiple times

Tags: android, xamarin

I am making an app with Xamarin Android. It has 4 turns, and I want a random picture+sound to display in every turn. So far so good, but now I want to make it in a way that it won't show the same picture+sound(the same random number) twice. I have tried some codes from other treads, but unfortunately that did not work.

Following is what I tried from the other treads:

```
if (ActivityGame.playing == false)
                                {
                                 List<int> alreadyGuessed = new List<int>();

                                    Random randomSound = new Random();
                                    int theSound = randomSound.Next(1, 5);
                                    while (alreadyGuessed.Contains(theSound))
                                        theSound = randomSound.Next(1, 5);
                                    alreadyGuessed.Add(theSound);

                                     return theSound;                               
                                }
```

Comment: Off-topic, but if (for whatever reason) you'll have 5 or more turns,  your `while` loop will turn into an endless loop. For robustness, you'll want to check that the `alreadyGuessed` list is smaller than the range of possible random values.

Comment: Good eye, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the `alreadyGuessed` list inside the if-branch. So, every time you get in that `if` branch, the program creates a new, **empty** list named `alreadyGuessed`.

You should make `alreadyGuessed` a member variable of your `ActivityGame` class, so it will retain the values already used.

Comment: Oh yea that's right, just a thing I tried after it didn't work outside the if-statement. It didn't work outside of it as well, unfortunately.

Comment: @JudithOtten Peculiar... I can't  see what else would be wrong. If the list is a member variable (and not declared in the method or something like that), it should work as intended. Consider printing the values in `alreadyGuessed` to the log, and see what is in it. Maybe that will give a hint.

Comment: I think I have found my mistake. I now put the list with all the variable declarations (I had it just outside the function first) which solved most of it. Second I had the button starting the game creating a random number, which did not have the same function yet (the putting things in list one). Looks like it's working for now in the console, let's hope it's not just coincidence :D 

Thank you :)